# Append function adds element to member of list

Tags: python, python-class

How to append Class object to a list without modifying its members?

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, type, children=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.children = children

    def add_child(self, child_node):
        self.children.append(child_node)

    def printNode(self, indent = 0):
        print(self.name + " has children " + str(len(self.children)))
        #for child in self.children: print(child, indent + 4)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = Node("A", "company")
    B = Node("B", "department")
    B.printNode()
    A.add_child(B)
    B.printNode()
```

The `append()` function adds node B to itself even though it should only add it to node A's children list, evident from output

```
B has children 0
B has children 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've stumbled onto a very common gotcha when defining arguments to functions in Python.  There's a good explanation [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

When you define a function the Python interpreter will create the values that are used as default arguments.  These default values are then used for every function call.  In this case the empty list `children=[]` gets created when `__init__` is interpreted.  Then the same list is used every time you call `add_child()` no matter which object it is called on.

Here's an example:

```py
def my_func(a_list=[]):
    a_list.append("something")
    print(a_list)

>>> my_func()
["something"]
>>> my_func()
["something", "something"]
```

In this case `a_list` is reused every function call and continues to grow in size.

The way to get around this is to use a different value to signify that the Node should start with an empty list of children.  Like so:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, type, children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.children = children or []

...
```

Answer (score 3):

Never use mutable data (such as lists) as default argument. Redefine your constructor like so and it'll work as expected

```
def __init__(self, name, type, children=None):
    self.name = name
    self.type = type
    self.children = children if children else []
```

Comment: Read more [here](https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/08/python-mutable-defaults-are-the-source-of-all-evil/#:~:text=Do%20not%20use%20mutable%20default,mutable%20value%20inside%20the%20function.) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)